# How to refund the payment using Paypal in ios?

Tags: ios, ios7, paypal

I am using paypal native sdk , in this there is no concept of refund payment. For this do we need REST API's? If we use REST API's then we need to get transaction id.  How can we achieve this?

Thanks , Suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be implemented with your server-side APIs (PayPal REST API - Refund a Sale).

1. A payment ID will be returned in the JSON response when your app makes a successful payment with a PayPal Mobile SDK.
2. Your app communicates with your server and sends the ID to your server
3. Your server can store the payment id value in a database, and look up the payment resource with a GET request to the payment uri, this is also to verify the mobile payment (by checking serveral fields in the response)
4. The JSON response will contain a Sale object in `related_resources`, with `"state": "completed"`, obtain the sale `id`, which will be used in the refund call
5. Make the refund API call, with the sale id from step#4

Reference links:

[Verify a mobile payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

[Refund API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#refund-a-sale)

Comment: Nice answer, Thanks for posting. Just now read the doc, its fabulous.